# Pattern for "unavailable" value when databinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

What is the typical pattern for displaying an "unavailable" value when databinding in WPF?

For example I am using MVVM, and `TextBlock`s in my view are bound to my viewmodel's properties, some of which are `int`s. There are times when I want to temporarily display two dashes ("--") in my view rather than the property value.

I could change the property to be a string, and then in the getter add some logic to specify whether it returns the value or "--". This is probably the appropriate way to use MVVM, but are there any easier ways?

Is there a way to take advantage of a `TextBlock`'s `FallbackValue`? Or is there another approach for temporarily suspending databinding and displaying a "unavailable" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FallbackValue` is only used when the binding path cannot be resolved, or the converter returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`. Converters are generally shunned when doing MVVM. My suggestion would be to have two properties, one that contains the `int` value and one that contains the display value:

```
public int SomeValue
{
    get { return _someValue; }
    set
    {
        if (_someValue != value)
        {
            _someValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeValue");
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeValueDisplay");
        }
    }
}

public string SomeValueDisplay
{
    get { return _someValue == -1 ? "--" : _someValue.ToString(); }
}
```

This gives you the best of both worlds. Your VM logic works with the `int` property, but your `TextBlock` binds directly to a `string` representation of the underlying `int`.

Comment: `SomeValueDisplay` should be a string, not int

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I would not actually need the second property--I can just change my property to a string directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `TextBlock` already displays text, why not just add a custom [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to the binding which returns `"--"` in case of, say, some `bool` value on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

WPF already uses converters behind the scenes (such as int to string) to display your values in the text blocks.  If you want to change the functionality, you can provide a simple custom converter to handle any special case you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a nullable int for the property, and in the binding specify TargetNullValue=--.

If you need the original value anyway, you could use your actual int value as backing store and use logic for determining whether to return the value or null.